# Assigning Cells To A Variant In a For Loop

Tags: vba

I have to enter thousands of cell references in vba.  So far, everything works, but I cannot figure out how to code "MyValue" into a for loop.  Any suggestions?

```
Dim MyValue1 As Variant
Dim MyValue2 As Variant
Dim MyValue3 As Variant
Dim MyValue4 As Variant
Dim MyValue5 As Variant


MyValue1 = Cells(3, 5).Value
MyValue2 = Cells(4, 5).Value
MyValue3 = Cells(5, 5).Value
MyValue4 = Cells(6, 5).Value
MyValue5 = Cells(7, 5).Value
```

Mooseman, each value needs to be unique in order to do an insert function via access.  When the code is written like this it works, however, I am looking for a looping function to accomplish the trick.

```
Dim MyVariant(1 To 5) As Variant
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 5
    MyVariant(i) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i + 2, 5)
Next i
```

I tried everyone's suggestions, but they do not seem to work.  This is the error message that I receive:

```
"Run-time error '-2147467259(80004005' Automation error Unspecified Error
```

Comment: Why is each myvalue variable unique?  What are you doing with all these values from cells().value?

Comment: please see my updated comments at the top of the page.

Comment: then your problem isn't with this code, it appears to be caused by your connection to Access (just guessing) - which line does this error occur on, we need to see that code instead

Answer (score 0):

use an array then loop:

```
Dim MyValue(0 to 9) As Variant
Dim i As Long

For i = 0 to 9
    MyValue(i) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i+2,5).Value
Next i
```

Or since the values are consecutive:

```
Dim MyValue() as Variant
MyValue = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(2,5),ActiveSheet.Cells(11,5)).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on what you want to do with `MyValue` but it can be as simple as:

```
Dim MyValue as Long
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To 11
    MyValue = Cells(i, 5)
Next i
```

But this only copies the value from the cells into a single variable.

You can also put all those values into an array like this:

```
Dim MyValue(2 To 11) as Long
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To 11
    MyValue(2) = Cells(i, 5)
Next i
```

You'll have to define more of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, dont. use an array instead:

```
Dim cellValues As Variant

cellValues = Range("E2:E100").Value

For i = 1 To UBound(cellValues)
    Debug.Print cellValues(i, 1)
Next
```